# how make the following html

Tags: css, html

I'm attaching a screenshot. I want to make html for that. Please help for
my html

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want table with columns like the following[image]

Comment: Have you heard of a things called `colspan` and `rowspan`?

Comment: Add some css your have tried. And your title isn't clear at all. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rowspan and colspan for header rows. Rest are simple tr and td.

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td colspan="2">C</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ROW1 - A</td>
    <td>ROW1 - B</td>
    <td>ROW1 - C</td>
    <td>ROW1 - D</td>
    <td>ROW1 - E</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ROW2 - A</td>
    <td>ROW2 - B</td>
    <td>ROW2 - C</td>
    <td>ROW2 - D</td>
    <td>ROW2 - E</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use html to format as you need, also use some css for your borders:

```
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 2px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">A</td>
   <td colspan="2">B</td>
   <td colspan="2">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>F</td>
   <td>G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>ROW1 - 1A</td>
   <td>ROW1 - 1B</td>
   <td>ROW1 - 1C</td>
   <td>ROW1 - 1D</td>
   <td>ROW1 - 1E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>ROW2 - 2A/td>
   <td>ROW2 - 2B</td>
   <td>ROW2 - 2C</td>
   <td>ROW2 - 2D</td>
   <td>ROW2 - 2E</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome @user7441072